# How to programmatically insert data into mysql from iPhone

Tags: iphone, mysql, xcode

I tried to insert data into mysql table in server using php server scripting, it's working fine.

Are there any possibilities to insert data into mysql table without calling the php server scripting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this link: http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/3711-access-mysql-remote-database-iphone.html

For some security issues, let this job to be done on the server. Use a REST (Representational state transfer) architecture to deal with your webservice.

Cheers,
VFN